# How to view my deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-posts

I see the post about [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) but it does not describe how to get to the deleted question. Can someone help with more detail?

Answer (score 8):

If you go to your profile, on the left side of your screen, you should see a list of your **Questions** and **Answers**

If you click on the heading for one of those lists, at the bottom of the page will be a link called: **deleted recent answers**.  or **deleted recent questions**.

If you click on that link, you should be brought to a list of your recently deleted questions/answers.

Comment: I get the list, but nowhere can I go to the deleted answer or question. As I invested some time answering, I would like to get at least my answer.